# Running C# code from Python tool for ArcMap?

Tags: python, arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, c#

It appears that the only way to copy individual rows of data while preserving GlobalIDs in code is by using [C# or VB.NET](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//00010000019v000000).

I need to run the C# code from the above link within a python tool, and I am curious if anyone knows proper techniques or any examples of doing this. I have come across a couple ways to execute C# code within python, such as [this](http://koichitamura.blogspot.com/2008/05/embedding-c-code-in-python.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260015/run-a-c-application-from-python-script), but I wanted to see if anyone could show me any examples or tips on doing this for ArcMap 10.

Also, I know that writing the whole script in C# using arcobjects would probably be the 'best' solution, but my organization would like to keep all of our tools in python.

Answer (score 4):

There are [Python for .NET bindings](http://pythonnet.sourceforge.net/):

> Python for .NET is a package that gives Python programmers nearly
>   seamless integration with the .NET Common Language Runtime (CLR) and
>   provides a powerful application scripting tool for .NET developers.
>   Using this package you can script .NET applications or build entire
>   applications in Python, using .NET services and components written in
>   any language that targets the CLR (Managed C++, C#, VB, JScript).